# How do I prevent auto reload page when ng serve for one time?

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, command-line-interface, angular-cli

Sometimes I make few css sketch updates in Chrome, see that it is exactly the updates I need. Then I add them to css file. And at this step, I have to save the css file. But after saving I lose my sketch updates in Chrome. It's ok if I make all changes in css file correctly. But in case I did some misprint or forget to copy some css style I have to check what did I wrong because I can't check with sketch updates in Chrome.

How do I prevent auto reload page when ng serve for one time?

Comment: Are you running `ng serve --watch`?

Comment: @cgTag no, just `ng serve` like in the get started page wroten [https://cli.angular.io]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start your dev server with:

```
ng serve --live-reload false
```

Docs here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve

If that doesn't work then do:

```
ng serve --live-reload=false
```

You could run two dev servers at same time as follows:

```
ng serve // with live reload on port 4200

ng serve --live-reload=false --port=4300 // without live reload on port 4300
```

These could run concurrently.

Comment: Run two dev servers with different keys, cool advice, I like it